# How to use a promise as filter callback in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

**EDIT**: *The solution is at the end*

I've got a lot of components which I have to filter by some properties, the problem is I cannot resolve the promise before use it in the Array.filter() method.

here is what I'm doing now

```js
session.on("message_create", (msg) => {
  const matcher = new Matcher(msg);

  components
    .filter((c) => c.trigger == "message_create")
    .filter((c) => matcher.alias(c.alias))
    .filter(async (c) => await matcher.scope(c.scope))
    .forEach((c) => c.template(msg));
});
```

I'm not sure but I think that unsolved promises are always true... right?

Here is the code from matcher.scope()

```
async scope(pattern?: string): Promise<boolean> {
  const chat = await this._msg.getChat();
  const contact = await chat.getContact();

  pattern = pattern ?? "anywhere";

  if (pattern == "anywhere") {
    console.log("anywhere");
    return true;
  }

  if (pattern == "group_only" && contact.isGroup) {
    console.log("group_only");
    return true;
  }

  if (pattern == "private_only" && contact.isUser) {
    console.log("private_only");
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

If you can help me to reduce the condition amount it will help me a lot too. Thanks

**EDIT**: *I marked this question as a duplicate because the original post helped me a lot in fixing my issue. It's still a work in progress, but for now it's good enough*

First of all I made a method which could filter arrays by passing async functions as callback, so I tried to return "this" to build a method chaining. That was a really bad idea. I had to use a lot of .then or await, so it became far more complicated than I thought.

Then I tried to make some kind of "interface". A synchronous function would handle the method chaning logic building the ".then thing" and returning the this

Here is what I finally came up with

```js
class Handler {
  constructor(array) {
    this.array = array
    this.queue = Promise.resolve(this.array)
  }

  async asyncFilter(acall, array) {
    let aux = []

    for (let item of array)
      await acall(item) && aux.push(item)

    return aux
  }

  filter(acall) {
    this.queue = this.queue.then(array => this.asyncFilter(acall, array))

    return this
  }

  async resolve() {
    let aux = await this.queue
    this.queue = Promise.resolve(this.array)

    return aux
  }
}
```

```js
async function main() {
  let handler = new Handler([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

  let result1 = handler
    .filter(elem => elem % 2 == 0)
    .filter(elem => elem > 5)

  console.log(await result1.resolve())

  let result2 = handler
    .filter(async elem => elem % 2 != 0)
    .filter(async elem => elem > 5)

  console.log(await result2.resolve())

  let result3 = handler
    .filter(elem => elem % 2 != 0)
    .filter(elem => elem < 5)

  console.log(await result3.resolve())
}

main()
```

And that's the result

```
PS C:\Users\Smith\Desktop\Javascript\Async> node .\main.js
[ 6, 8, 10 ]
[ 7, 9 ]
[ 1, 3 ]
```

I appreciate whoever tried to help me. I will work on improving my code, handling errors and so on. That's it, thanks guys

Comment: Im going to try. I think the result of the array will be a promise too, so idk how the library that Im using will handle it

Comment: Nobody is going to call you stupid because you are a beginner. But on the other hand, such async patterns may be quite complex and ad a beginner you should probably start with understanding the basics and then move on to more complex things

Comment: async is quite complex for me. I can deal with async/await sometimes, but use Promise class and then/catch is hard

Answer (score 1):

```
async scope(pattern: string = 'anywhere'): Promise<boolean> {
  try {
    const chat = await this._msg.getChat();
    const contact = await chat.getContact();

    return pattern === 'anywhere' || pattern == "group_only" && contact.isGroup || pattern == "private_only" && contact.isUser; 
  } catch (err) {
    return false; // if any of the promises failed
  }
}
```

And for the main function

```
session.on("message_create", async (msg) => { // move async here
```

Comment: thanks, it helped to use async inside event callback